# Проблеми с отбором информации при помощи List Comprehention

Tags: python

Проблема в том, что из выпадающего списка `netsh wlan show profiles` мне нужна информация из строки `all user profiles`. При использовании list comprehention, print выводит 1. Кто знает, как можно это оптимизировать и реализовать отбор информации из нужной строки?

```py
import os

f = open('text.txt', 'w')

Ext_Wifi_Pass = os.system ('netsh wlan show profiles' + Users +  'key=clear')
print (Ext_Wifi_Pass)

for index in 'Ext_Wifi_Pass':
    f.write(index)
```

Comment: проблема в том что из випадающего списка netsh wlan show profiles мне нужна информация из стороки all user profiles при использовании List Comprehention в print вбивает 1 кто знает как можно ето оптимизировать и реализовать отбор информации из нужной строки

Comment: что еще за выпадающее окно? окно консоли, что ли? И где  у вас в коде list comprehension?